# ts: why Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Tags: typescript

```
type AssertPositive<N extends number> =
  number extends N ?
     N :
    `${N}` extends `-${string}` ? never : N;

class Millseconds<N extends number> {
  constructor(public readonly value: AssertPositive<N>){
      if(this.value < 0){
          throw new Error('Value Cannot Smaller Than 0');
      }
  }
}
```

```
new Millseconds(1); // OK

// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.(2345)
new Millseconds(-1); // Error
```

new Millsecond(-1) why -1 parameter of type "never"？

type of parameter-1 , Why no access to condition 1

```
 number extends N  ？ N  : `${N}` extends `-${string}` ? never : N

conditon1 : N
condition2:  `${N}` extends `-${string}` ? never : N
```

I want to know what causes

Comment: This is not an ideal filter: both `new Millseconds(1-2); ` and `let x = -1; new Millseconds(x);` don't produce errors, since the value of `N` is just `number` (not a specific number) so `number extends N` evaluates to `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the type (reformatted for clarity):

```
type AssertPositive<N extends number> =
  number extends N
    ? N
    : `${N}` extends `-${string}`
      ? never
      : N;
```

If we take `-1` as the value for `N`, then the condition `number extends -1` evaluates to false, thus prompting the evaluation of the second condition.

The `extends` clause is defined in terms of *generalization* and *specialization*: `specific extends general` evaluates to true, while `general extends specific` evaluates to false.

The inverse condition, i.e. `-1 extends number`, would evaluate to true.

Comment: ok, thank u , I understand. it's means, if we take 0 as the value for N, then the condition number extends 0 evaluates to false, but  `${N}` extends `-${string}` ->  0 extends  `-0` is false ,so return 0

Comment: Zero and negative zero are somewhat of a special case. In TypeScript, both `0 extends -0` and `-0 extends 0` evaluate to true. And in JavaScript `0 === -0` too (although they are actually not entirely equal).